Unable to create sprite svg file from multiple svg files using webpack
I want to generate a single sprite svg file from multiple svg files.would like to use webpack for it.am unable to get the sprite svg created whatsoever.
I have tried with webpack 5 first. but it didn't work since the svg-sprite-loader doesn't support it yet. so downgraded to webpack 4.
Here's my webpack config:
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"), // the bundle output path
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: "bundle.js", // the name of the bundle
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html", // to import index.html file inside index.js
    }),
    new SpriteLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 3030, // you can change the port
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // excluding the node_modules folder
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // styles files
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
            options: {
              extract: true,
              publicPath: '/static/'
            }
          },
          'svgo-loader'
        ]
      }]
}
};

whatsoever, sprite file is not created. public path static is also not created. Can someone help please?
Here's my package.json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "svgo-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.47.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.2"
  }
}


